# Laravel 5.2 Call to undefined method even method exists

Tags: laravel

I have many to many relationship between `User` and `Permission` model

User Model

```
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class); 
    }

    public function tambahPermission($permission){
        if(is_string($permission)){
            $permission = Permission::where('name', $permission)->first();      
        }

        return $this->permissions()->attach($permission);
    }
```

And successfully run this seeder

```
$userAdmin = App\Models\User::create([
           'full_name' => 'Admin Full Name',
           'address' => 'JL. Kalij',
           'phone' => 0857,
           'family_name' => 'Rizky Family Admin',
           'family_address' => 'JL. Kandangan',
           'family_phone' => 085799996666,
           'password' => bcrypt('123456789'),
           'email' => 'admin@domain.co.id',
           'status' => 'confirmed',
           'balance' => 0,
          ]);

        $userAdmin->tambahPermission('index.post');
```

Then I try to add other permission for specific user via tinker like this

```
$user = App\Models\User::find(3); $user->tambahPermission('create.post');
```

But I get this error

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tambahPermission()'
```

**UPDATED**

I run this in my tinker

```
>>> $user = App\Models\User::find(3); 
=> App\Models\User {#750
     id: "3",
     email: "admin@kika.co.id",
     full_name: "Admin Full Name",
     address: "JL. Kalijudan 226 D",
     phone: "0",
     family_name: "Rizky Family Admin",
     family_address: "JL. Kandangan",
     family_phone: "0",
     idcard: null,
     status: "confirmed",
     balance: "0",
     created_at: "2016-10-25 10:34:40",
     updated_at: "2016-10-25 10:34:40",
   }
>>> $user->tambahPermission('create.post');
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tambahPermission()'
```

`tambahPermission()` method is exists in user model.

What's wrong with my code?
Why it successfully run on seeder but not on tinker?

What I want is add extra permission for specific user.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try : `$user = App\Models\User::find(3); $user->load('permissions'); $user->tambahPermission('create.post');`

Comment: nope. still failed

Comment: Do you run `$user = App\Models\User::find(3); $user->tambahPermission('create.post');` all in one line? If yes, can you break it into two lines and execute the query first before calling your custom method?

Comment: @ArminSam still same

Comment: it's weird find() returns an instance of query builder instead of model or null ... I don't understand

Comment: @RimonKhan Using the scope prefix on a funtion that saves relationships, doen't make sense. Scope should be used to modify / filter a resulting set of objects

Comment: Maybe `composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan clear-compiled` would help.

Comment: @ArminSam did'nt help :(

Comment: @ArminSam then how should be if I want to add permission for specific user?

Comment: can you post the entire user class?

Answer (score 0):

find() returns the collection instead of model, where as create() returns the model instance.

When you check the function of create:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{

$model = new static($attributes);

$model->save();

return $model;
}
```

function returns the instance after saving the data where as the find() returns the collection...

Comment: then how should if I want to add permission for spesific user, let's just assume I want to update permission for specific user? Usually I use Model::find() .. so on .. $var->save() to update.

Comment: find() doesn't return collection if given a single id, it returns model.